# NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I have got this error

```
NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.R$styleable
```

I read a lot of tutorials, but it did not help me.

1. Project structure -> Import module -> google play services lib
2. My project -> Module Dependency -> add google play services lib
3. Add google play services jar file.

My xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Activity is:

```
public class FlatOnMap extends Activity {
private GoogleMap googleMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
    try {
        initilizeMap();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();
}
}
```

My Manifest is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>
<permission
        android:name="ua.khuta.ALHANAi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="ua.khuta.ALHANAi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>

<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        >
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            >
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value=".SearchResultsActivity"/>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait"
              android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
            >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".FlatInfo"/>
    <activity android:name=".FlatOnMap"/>
    <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="myApiKey"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

My Solution:
 I have uppdated my google play servises, and import it again, but i does not add .jar file.
1. Import Module -> google_play_servises_lib project
2. + Add library -> google_play_servises_lib

Comment: Are you using Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see some potential issues:

1. You might have imported `com.google.android.gms.R` somewhere in your
   code and not the one that belongs to your app.
2. The `<permission>` on your manifest is obsolete; not needed anymore.
3. `<uses-permission android:name="ua.khuta.ALHANAi.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>` is obsolete
4. You are missing this inside your `<application>`:

   ```
    <meta-data
       android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
       android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
   ```
5. You have declared an `Activity` (`MyActivity`) as a `MAIN` and `LAUNCHER` twice in your `AndroidManifest`; remove one of the `<intent-filter>...</intent-filter>`:

   ```
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
           <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
       </intent-filter>
   ```

Comment: Android Resource Packaging:\AndroidManifest.xml:63: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version'). But when i press cntrl and "google_play_services_version" - i opened this file

Comment: Then I think it definitely means you are not importing the library correctly.

Comment: The first part of my question is way is about how i imported library. Check it please

Comment: I do not use IntelliJ, so I do not know how libraries are imported. Sorry.

Comment: I think it is the same way like in android studio

Comment: Android Studio uses gradle as a build system, so you can add the dependency in the build.gradle file inside the `dependency{}`. Also, it seems that you are adding the library and also the .jar?

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Make sure you mark this question as answered. Happy coding